# Ctags: tags file for SystemVerilog incorrect

Tags: ctags, universal-ctags

I'm trying to generate a tags file for a directory with .sv files. The tags file didn't work as intended and anytime I go to an instance declaration it send me to some random place. Looking at the ctags -h command it doesn't include systemverilog as supported language which makes me think I have the wrong installation but I'm not sure. I install this version of ctags ([universal ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags)). Online documentation hasn't helped. Can anyone share how they generate tags for .sv files?

Comment: Universal ctags verilog parser also parses system verilog, so please report any issues you are finding in its GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an installation of an older ctags. Once I used the correct one /path/to/ctags it worked.